# Python: How to keep repeating a program until a specific input is obtained?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a function that evaluates input, and I need to keep asking for their input and evaluating it until they enter a blank line. How can I set that up?

```
while input != '':
    evaluate input
```

I thought of using something like that, but it didn't exactly work. Any help?

Comment: How does it not work? What does it do? What do you expect to see?

Comment: That above code repeatedly asks for the input if it is not ''. I need it to evaluate input until a blank line is entered.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  First is like this:

```
while True:             # Loop continuously
    inp = raw_input()   # Get the input
    if inp == "":       # If it is a blank line...
        break           # ...break the loop
```

The second is like this:

```
inp = raw_input()       # Get the input
while inp != "":        # Loop until it is a blank line
    inp = raw_input()   # Get the input again
```

Note that if you are on Python 3.x, you will need to replace `raw_input` with `input`.

Comment: This will raise an EOF error at the last input if there is no further input

Comment: @SnigdhaBatra You can avoid it with:
    except EOFError:
        break

Comment: Every time I write a while loop where the variable that the condition checks is set inside the loop (so that you have to initialize that variable before the loop, like in your second example), it doesn't feel right. And then I search for `python repeat until` to remind myself that I should just accept that feeling :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a small program that will keep asking an input until required input is given.

we should keep the required number as a **string**, otherwise it may not work. input is taken as string by default

```html
required_number = '18'

while True:
    number = input("Enter the number\n")
    if number == required_number:
        print ("GOT IT")
        break
    else:
        print ("Wrong number try again")
```

**or you can use eval(input()) method**

```python
required_number = 18

while True:
    number = eval(input("Enter the number\n"))
    if number == required_number:
        print ("GOT IT")
        break
    else:
        print ("Wrong number try again")
```

Comment: Actually, it keeps repeating even _after_ the required input is given.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to use a separate value that tracks if the input is valid:

```
good_input = None
while not good_input:
     user_input = raw_input("enter the right letter : ")
     if user_input in list_of_good_values: 
        good_input = user_input
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier way:

```
required_number = 18

user_number = input("Insert a number: ")
while f"{required_number} != user_number:
    print("Oops! Something is wrong")
    user_number = input("Try again: ")
print("That's right!")

#continue the code
```