# While statement ja/nee

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, passwords

How do i get my while statement to stop when the user inserts "nee" & exits the program. At the moment when the users inserts nee it keeps on running the program and asking ("Wilt u dit programme gebruiken ? ja/nee: ") for 3 times. After it has asked me for 3 times the program abruptly stops.

I want the program to run when the users inserts ja and to stop when the user inserts nee.

```
import time
    import sys

    print ("Check of uw wachtwoord veilig genoeg is in dit programma.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Uw wachtwoord moet tussen minimaal 6 en maximaal 12 karakters
    bestaan")
    print ("U kunt gebruik maken van hoofdletters,getallen en symbolen  
    (@,#,$,%)")


    klein = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    groot = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
    'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    nummers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
    symbolen= [' ', '!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '"', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-',
    '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 
    '{', '|', '}', '~',"'"]


    def ok(passwd,l):
        return any(k in passwd for k in l)  # checkt of een letter in de lijst  
    in het wachtwoord zit.

    while input("Wilt u dit programma gebruiken? ja/nee: ") == "ja" or   input("Wilt u dit programma gebruiken? ja/nee: ") == "JA" or input("Wilt u dit programma gebruiken? ja/nee: ") == "Ja":
    ww = input("Voer uw wachtwoord in: ")
    if len(ww) < 6:
        print ("uw wachtwoord is te kort, uw wachtwoord moet uit minimaal 6 en maximaal 12 karakters bestaan!")
    elif len(ww) > 12:
        print ("uw wachtwoord is te lang, uw wachtwoord moet uit minimaal 6 en maximaal 12 karakters bestaan!")
    elif len(ww) >= 6 and len(ww)<= 12:
        sww = set(ww)           # set is een onorganiseerde verzameling dat betekent dat het niet op order is bijv. SaUj%2F3 = Oonorganiseerd        
        if all(ok(sww,l) for l in [klein,groot,nummers,symbolen]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Zeer sterk")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [klein,groot,nummers]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Sterk")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [klein,groot,symbolen]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Sterk")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [groot,nummers,symbolen]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Sterk")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [nummers,symbolen,klein]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Sterk")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [nummers,symbolen]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Medium")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [groot,nummers]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Medium")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [groot,symbolen]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Medium")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [klein,groot]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Medium")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [klein,nummers]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Medium")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [klein,symbolen]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Medium")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [klein]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Zwak")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [symbolen]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Zwak")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [nummers]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Zwak")
        elif all(ok(sww,l) for l in [groot]):
            print ("uw wachtwoord is Zwak")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are asking for it three times. When the first condition (`== "ja"`) is wrong it goes on to the next condition (`== "JA"`). In your case it would then ask a second time for your input. Try doing it with [a `while true` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337489/python-how-to-keep-repeating-a-program-until-a-specific-input-is-obtained):

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Wilt u dit programma gebruiken? ja/nee: ")
    if inp == "nee":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, checking for `.lower()` to capture "ja", "Ja", and "JA":

Also, using `getpass.getpass()` instead of `input()` for the actual password prevents "local echo on screen" ... so nobody can look over your shoulder when using this.

```
import time
import sys
import getpass

KLEIN = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
GROOT = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
NUMMERS = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
SYMBOLEN = [' ', '!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '"', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~',"'"]


def printinstruction():
    print("Check of uw wachtwoord veilig genoeg is in dit programma.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Uw wachtwoord moet tussen minimaal 6 en maximaal 12 karakters bestaan")
    print("U kunt gebruik maken van hoofdletters,getallen en SYMBOLEN  (@,#,$,%)")

def ok(passwd, l):
    return any(k in passwd for k in l)  # checkt of een letter in de lijst  in het wachtwoord zit.

def checkww(ww):
    if len(ww) < 6:
        print ("uw wachtwoord is te kort, uw wachtwoord moet uit minimaal 6 en maximaal 12 karakters bestaan!")
    elif len(ww) > 12:
        print ("uw wachtwoord is te lang, uw wachtwoord moet uit minimaal 6 en maximaal 12 karakters bestaan!")
    elif len(ww) >= 6 and len(ww) <= 12:
        sww = set(ww)           # set is een onorganiseerde verzameling dat betekent dat het niet op order is bijv. SaUj%2F3 = Oonorganiseerd        
        if all(ok(sww, l) for l in [KLEIN, GROOT, NUMMERS, SYMBOLEN]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Zeer sterk")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [KLEIN, GROOT, NUMMERS]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Sterk")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [KLEIN, GROOT, SYMBOLEN]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Sterk")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [GROOT, NUMMERS, SYMBOLEN]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Sterk")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [NUMMERS, SYMBOLEN, KLEIN]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Sterk")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [NUMMERS, SYMBOLEN]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Medium")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [GROOT, NUMMERS]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Medium")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [GROOT, SYMBOLEN]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Medium")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [KLEIN ,GROOT]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Medium")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [KLEIN, NUMMERS]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Medium")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [KLEIN, SYMBOLEN]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Medium")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [KLEIN]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Zwak")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [SYMBOLEN]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Zwak")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [NUMMERS]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Zwak")
        elif all(ok(sww, l) for l in [GROOT]):
            print("uw wachtwoord is Zwak")

def main():
    printinstruction()
    while True:
        gebruik = input("Wilt u dit programma gebruiken? ja/nee: ")
        if gebruik.lower() == 'ja':
            ww = getpass.getpass("Voer uw wachtwoord in: ")
            checkww(ww)
        if gebruik.lower() == 'nee':
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `checkww()` function would be quite large and repetitive, this could be shortened, by introducing a global RESPONSE dictionary, and counting a "factor" to determine the correct response.

At the top of your code (same as the other global variables) you can put the dictionary:

```
RESPONSE = {1: "uw wachtwoord is Zwak", 2: "uw wachtwoord is Medium", 3: "uw wachtwoord is Sterk", 4: "uw wachtwoord is Zeer sterk"}
```

Then replace the checkww() with this:

```
def checkww(ww):
    factor = 0
    if len(ww) < 6:
        print ("uw wachtwoord is te kort, uw wachtwoord moet uit minimaal 6 en maximaal 12 karakters bestaan!")
        return
    elif len(ww) > 12:
        print ("uw wachtwoord is te lang, uw wachtwoord moet uit minimaal 6 en maximaal 12 karakters bestaan!")
        return    
    sww = set(ww)
    if all(ok(sww, l) for l in [KLEIN]): factor += 1
    if all(ok(sww, l) for l in [GROOT]): factor += 1
    if all(ok(sww, l) for l in [NUMMERS]): factor += 1
    if all(ok(sww, l) for l in [SYMBOLEN]): factor += 1
    print(RESPONSE.get(factor, "Ooops - something went wrong"))
```

HTH, Edwin.