# Show an error message to the user if what they entered is not a float

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code:

```
print('Welcome To The Balance Tracker!')
balance = float(input('Enter Your Starting Balance: ')
```

This is at the start of the program. How would I make it so the user cannot proceed unless the balance is a float, and if they enter anything else it shows an error message?

I know it probably has to be in a while loop. I'm just not a 100% sure on the execution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to keep repeating a program until a specific input is obtained?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337489/python-how-to-keep-repeating-a-program-until-a-specific-input-is-obtained)

Answer (score 1):

Catching the ValueError that is raised if `float` fails will solve your problem.

```
print('Welcome To The Balance Tracker!')
balance = None
while balance is None:
    try:
        balance = float(input('Enter Your Starting Balance: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("HEY! '{}' is not a float!".format(balance))
```

This will print a message if it's not float and while loop will not let user to go through!

Comment: This code will run in neither python2 (because there is no `input`) nor in python3 (because print requires parens). The inquirer was looking for python3.

Comment: @AlesL your comment is self contradictory! Very first, this is for python-3, so there is no need to talk about python-2. First run this program, and then judge rather than just down voting any thing in your way!

Comment: you have added parens around the final print, so now it will work!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
is_balance_not_float = True
print('Welcome To The Balance Tracker!')
while (is_balance_not_float):
    try:
        balance = float(input('Enter Your Starting Balance: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("You are suppose to enter a number. ")
    else:
        is_balance_not_float = False

print("Balance : %s" % balance)
```

Comment: Why negative Vote ?

Comment: If you try running this, you will discover that there is a problem... `isinstance(balance, float)` is always going to return False, because input() always returns a string, never a numeric type.

Comment: @AlexL everything is not meant to be down-voted. Comment, observe and then act.

Comment: The problem with isinstance() here is that it tells you whether something IS a float, not whether it COULD BE CONVERTED to a float, which is really what you are trying to figure out...and the best way to determine that is probably to try to convert it, and see if it works...

Comment: How could you except NameError? It's a ValueError and balance is outer from the scope at last line.

Comment: @abhinav Typo :P

Answer (score -2):

The best thing to do is to try to convert the input to a float, and if it fails, then try again. Reasons for failure could include a string that is not convertible to float, or an EOF on stdin.

For instance:

```
balance = None
while balance is None:
    try:
        balance = float(input('Enter Your Starting Balance: '))
    except Exception:
        print('Balance must be a (floating point) number')
```

As a point of interest, if the user hits Control-C, it raises `KeyboardInterrupt`, which is *not* a subclass of `Exception`, and so will *not* get caught by the except, and will cause the program to exit.

Comment: Exception is a broad clause. Kindly be specific. Raise a ValueError!

Comment: Please answer with an explanation. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: What about if I enter 55, its an int . Not float Value

Comment: @abhinav you could make the case for `ValueError`, but I like the broader `Exception` in this case, since it is interactive.

Comment: @AbhilashJoseph the string '55' will happily convert to a float.

    >>> float('55')
    55.0