# How do I restart a python script with a command

Tags: python

So, I've been having troubles with restarting a script within itself. I'm making a simple program and I want to have a choice for example:

```
print ('would you like to make another calculation')

choice3 = input(' Choose: [Y], [N]')

if choice3.lower() == 'y':
    print ('OK!')
    time.sleep(3)
```

and I want to have it restart right there. If anyone could help me out, thanks... I really appreciate it

Comment: I would suggest using a while loop instead of restarting your script. [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337489/python-how-to-keep-repeating-a-program-until-a-specific-input-is-obtained)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `loop`:

```
while True:
    print ('would you like to make another calculation')
    choice3 = input(' Choose: [Y], [N]')
    if choice3.lower() == 'y':
        print ('OK!')
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks, I really appreciate it