# Why is my python code not exiting correctly?

Tags: python, function

I made a code that prompts me to input a 4 digit number and it checks if it is a valid 4 digit number. Then, it will ask if I would like to enter another 4 digit or terminate the program.
However, when I input the 4 digits wrongly and would like to terminate the program, it still runs through the main()...

```
def numbervalid(n):
    length1 = len(n)
    
    for i in range(0,length1):
            if n[i] >= 'A' and n[i] <= 'Z' or n[i] >= 'a' and n[i] <= 'z':
                print("==> Non digits in card\n")
                anotherno()     

    if length1 < 4 and length1 > 2: 
        print("==> In valid length\n")
        
        anotherno() 
           
    elif length1 > 4:
        print("==> Too many numbers\n")
        
        anotherno() 
          
    elif length1 < 3:
        print("==> Too few numbers\n") 
        
        anotherno() 
    

def anotherno():
        n = input("Another card (y/Y/n/N): ")
        if n == "y" or n == "Y":
            print("--------------------------------------------")
            main()
        elif n == "n" or n == "N":
            print("program terminated")
        else:
            print("Please enter only y/Y/n/N")
            anotherno() 

def main():
    n = input("Enter a 4 digit number: ")
    numbervalid(n)

    print("Testing")
    
    anotherno() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main ()
```

This is the output:

```
Enter a 4 digit number: 123
==> In valid length     

Another card (y/Y/n/N): n
program terminated      
Testing
Another card (y/Y/n/N): n
program terminated
```

If I input the digits wrongly for 2 times in a row, it will do this

```
Enter a 4 digit number: 123
==> In valid length     

Another card (y/Y/n/N): y
--------------------------------------------
Enter a 4 digit number: 123
==> In valid length     

Another card (y/Y/n/N): n
program terminated
Testing
Another card (y/Y/n/N): n
program terminated
Testing
Another card (y/Y/n/N): n
program terminated
```

I would like the program to terminate after I input "n" or "N" once.

Comment: I think it's because of the recursive calls to `main()` from `anotherno()`??

Comment: You already calling the `anotherno` inside the `numbervalid`. It asks for `Y/N` question. Then exists the `anotherno` called by the `numbervalid`. Next you call the `anotherno` again inside the `main`. TL;DR: You over-complicated the the code. Try to write it simpler...

Comment: `main` calls `anotherno`, which in turn calls `main`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to keep repeating a program until a specific input is obtained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337489/python-how-to-keep-repeating-a-program-until-a-specific-input-is-obtained)

Answer (score 1):

Your use of recursion is inappropriate for this. You should use a *while True* construct and stay in that loop until such time as your criteria have been validated.

For example:

```
def get_number() -> int:
    while True:
        value = input("Enter a 4-digit number: ")
        try:
            rv = int(value)
            if 1000 <= rv <= 9999:
                return rv
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print(f"\a{value} is not a 4-digit number")

def main() -> tuple[int, ...]:
    first_number = get_number()
    while True:
        reply = input("Another card (y/Y/n/N): ")
        if reply in set("nN"):
            print("Program terminated")
            break
        if reply in set("yY"):
            second_number = get_number()
            return first_number, second_number
        print("\aInvalid response")
    return -1, -1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x, y = main()
    if x > 0:
        print(f"Your numbers are {x} and {y}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The example posted is an unusual use of recursion. I would remove all calls of `anotherno` from `numbervalid`. With `anotherno` only called as the last line of `main`, only two functions will be recursing on each other and the `anotherno` function will work as expected.

```
Enter a 4 digit number: 8755
Testing
Another card (y/Y/n/N): n
program terminated
```

```
Enter a 4 digit number: 9353
Testing
Another card (y/Y/n/N): Y
--------------------------------------------
Enter a 4 digit number: 4685
Testing
Another card (y/Y/n/N): y
--------------------------------------------
Enter a 4 digit number: 58
==> Too few numbers

Testing
Another card (y/Y/n/N): y
--------------------------------------------
Enter a 4 digit number: 4764
Testing
Another card (y/Y/n/N): n
program terminated
```

Failing that, you could make `anotherno` return a boolean and use a while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

That is not what recursion is used for. You are just stacking up method calls and decreasing efficiency.
This could be a solution, you must not use recursion in this case"

```
def validate_number(n):
try:
     num = int(n) #validates it is a number
     if num < 1000: #too small
        print("==> Too few numbers\n")
     if num > 9999: #too big
        print("==> Too many numbers\n")             
     return 1000 <= num <=9999 #number ok
except ValueError: #if not number
     print("==> Non digits in card\n")
     return False

def main():
n = ''
while n not in ['n', 'N']: #if not, end
    n = input("Enter a 4 digit number: ")
    validate_number(n)
    n = input("Another card (y/Y/n/N): ")
    while n not in ['n', 'N', 'y', 'Y']: #if not ['n', 'N', 'y', 'Y'], keep asking
        print("Please enter only y/Y/n/N")
        n = input("Another card (y/Y/n/N): ")
    if n in ['y', 'Y']: #if yes, ask another number
        print("--------------------------------------------")
print("program terminated")
```

Answer (score -1):

exit() missing after print("program terminated") in your n case. You are not telling Python to end

Comment: That's nonsense. To cite the [documentation of `exit` and `quit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit): "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs."